# Webcams in HTML5 without Flash or Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, flash, html, webcam

So now Adobe has pulled the plug on Mobile Flash and are pushing more for HTML5, and Silverlight has pulled the plug too, what's next for interactive video content.

So if they die out (as they are currently trying to do) how do we access web cams (or even phone cams) on websites. The HTML5 Media Capture looks like it doesn't support streams only Files, so that could be out, is there any alternatives at the moment, or in the near future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the following links. Although support may be poor

**Media capturing** api http://www.w3.org/TR/media-capture-api/

**Device tag** https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-implementing-device-and-stream-management-webkit

**Webcam Capturing** http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2011/03/23/webcam-orientation-preview

Comment: Isn't "no support" closer to the truth than "support may be poor", right now? Is there any support in any officially released browser (that is not a technology preview or beta or such)?

Comment: Latest vertion of one of the browser(i cant remember but it's opera 12 i think) supports device api.

Comment: It will be an interesting race to see who develops it in time, its a big area which is heavily utilized by flash right now which is leaving a black hole.

Answer (score 1):

Some more resources that's appeared since this question was asked :-

[GetUserMedia tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

[GetUserMedia specs](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html)

[More info on GetUserMedia](http://html5doctor.com/getusermedia/)

Answer (score 0):

GetUserMedia is useless if you want useful video content for production.
You can turn on the webcam but no way to save them to remote server with any sort of controls.

Some people used whammy.js library to create webm movie from the stream.

And yet, you can't record audio and video at the same time!?!

Flash with FMS/WOWZA/Red5 still the way to go if you want a complete solution.